# Python - Grouping Rows into List

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
TransactionID     ProductID
1                 132
1                 256
1                 985
2                 321
3                 451
3                 219
```

I want to group by the 'TransactionID' and assign the 'ProductID' to a list, like this:

```
list = [[132, 256, 985], [321], [451, 291]]
```

What is the proper way to performe this task?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `print df.groupby('TransactionID')['ProductID'].apply(list).values.tolist()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might help. 
You simply group them by the `TransactionID` and then take the `ProductID` from it and convert to list

```
 grouped_list = list(df.groupby('TransactionID')['ProductID'].apply(list))
```

As mentioned in the comments, it is not good to use 'list' as your variable name. This is because you will re-define the original function of the list command by setting it to the grouped list that you extracted from the df.

Comment: Best to avoid naming the result `list` otherwise next time you try and run similar code in that scope, things are likely to break because `list` is an actual list and not the builtin... (`product_ids` would seem a reasonably descriptive and useful name)

Comment: Yes, I've just used it to match with what's written in the question. 
It's not a good idea to use that as a var name. 
Will update it.

Comment: I am getting the following error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: It seems you have over written `list` with some other value.
I would suggest to restart the kernel. But make sure you have not written `list = ...` anywhere in your code. You will again rewrite the original function of your list

Comment: Great. If possible, please approve the answer :)  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

the following is not so good but can work.

```
result = [list(i.ProductID) for i in dict(list(df.groupby("TransactionID"))).values()]
```